# Why is docker taking up a lot of space and what to do about it?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

On my server, the docker directory takes up a lot of space:

```
52G /var/lib/docker
```

I cleaned up all unused "garbage" with this command:

```
docker system prune --all
```

This command freed 1Gb on initial execution, and now it gives this:

> Total reclaimed space: 0B

And this command `docker system df` shows:

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              5                   5                   6.265GB             1.372GB (21%)
Containers          12                  12                  48.92MB             0B (0%)
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

Tell me, please, in what way can I still free up space on the server?

Comment: `docker system prune --all --volumes`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Also shows "0B"

Comment: You have running container that prevents you from deleting some volumes and images, that's why.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I don't have volumes at all

Comment: can you also check if your container is logging to standard output , if yes then it stores all the logs in local directory /var/lib/container/container-id , you need to handle that via various logging drivers